# Having an error for checking existing user in my mongodb database

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb

I'm trying to check that the user is already is exist in my database or not by email only. But I got the 'error registering user' when I submit my form and it not working properly. Without the if else condition, the code is working properly and it stores the values from that form, but it create redundancy in my database

Here's the code for my sign up form:-

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './style/Form.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function MyForm() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setpassword] = useState('');
    const [acceptedTerms, setAcceptedTerms] = useState(false);
    const [Interests, setInterests] = useState([]);
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!name || !email || !password || !acceptedTerms) {
            alert('Please fill out all required fields and accept terms.');
            return;
        }
        console.log('Name:', name);
        console.log('Email:', email);
        console.log('Accepted Terms:', acceptedTerms);
        console.log('Selected Option:', Interests);
        console.log('Password: ', password)
        alert("Name: " + name + " Password:" + password);

        try {
            const responce = await axios.post('api/checkUser', {email});

            if(responce.data.exists){
                alert("User with this email already exist. Please login instead.");
                navigate('/Form');
            }
            else{
                const userData = { name, email, password, Interests };
                await axios.post('/api/register', userData);
                alert("User registered successfully");
                // Clear form fields after successful registration
                setName('');
                setEmail('');
                setpassword('');
                setAcceptedTerms(false);
                setInterests([]);
                navigate('/');
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error registering user:', error);
            alert("Error registering user");
        }
    };
    const handleButtonClick = (buttonValue) => {
        const updatedInterests = [...Interests];
        const index = updatedInterests.indexOf(buttonValue);
        if (index === -1) {
            updatedInterests.push(buttonValue);
        } else {
            updatedInterests.splice(index, 1);
        }
        setInterests(updatedInterests);
    };
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='App'>
            <label>
                Name:
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} autoFocus required
                /><br />
            </label>
            <label>
                Email:
                <input
                    type="email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} required
                /><br />
            </label>
            <label>
                Password:
                <input
                    type="password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setpassword(e.target.value)} required
                /><br />
            </label>
            <label>
                <input className='check'
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={acceptedTerms}
                    onChange={(e) => setAcceptedTerms(e.target.checked)} required
                />
                I accept the terms and conditions
            </label><br />
            <p>Selete the topics from below that you want to read the most:-</p>
            <div className='checkOptions'>
                <p className="d-inline-wrap gap-1">
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className={`btn m-1 ${Interests.includes('All') ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleButtonClick('All')}
                    >
                        All
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className={`btn m-1 ${Interests.includes('Business') ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleButtonClick('Business')}
                    >
                        Business
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className={`btn m-1 ${Interests.includes('Science') ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleButtonClick('Science')}
                    >
                        Science
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className={`btn m-1 ${Interests.includes('Technology') ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleButtonClick('Technology')}
                    >
                        Technology
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className={`btn m-1 ${Interests.includes('Health') ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleButtonClick('Health')}
                    >
                        Health
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className={`btn m-1 ${Interests.includes('Sports') ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleButtonClick('Sports')}
                    >
                        Sports
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <link /><br /><br />
            <p>seems you have visited before?  <a href="Form">Sign in</a> now!</p>
        </form>
    );
}
```

I used to try different code for the encountering this problem, but it's not working properly.
Every time I got the same error that I got before

Comment: Why not just throw a 409 error from backend if email exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it the API itself like:

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public UserService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
  _userManager = userManager;
}

 public async Task<Status> Login(LoginViewModel logInViewModel, string baseUrl)

 {

  //Using Microsoft Identity Framework, User Manager will check either the user exists with the passed email address.

  ApplicationUser? applicationUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(logInViewModel.Email);

  if (applicationUser is null)
  {
      return new Status(true, $"Unable to login as user '{logInViewModel.Email}' not found.", 404);
  }

  if (!applicationUser.EmailConfirmed)
  {
      return new Status(true, $"Unable to login. Please verify your account. your email: {logInViewModel.Email} is not verified yet", 401);
  }

  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(applicationUser, logInViewModel.Password, false, false);

  if (!result.Succeeded)
  {
      return new Status(true, $"login failed. User name or password is incorrect.", 401);
  }

}
```

This is my login endpoint where API first checks if the user does not exists then returns equivalent response else it logs the user in. So you can use similar functionality and if the user exists return from there otherwise register the new user.

FYI I am using .Net Core Web API with identity framework for my back end logic